# Roslyn changing node references

Tags: roslyn

Because nodes are immutable and every time new instances are created my references become stale. What's the best approach to handle this? I am refactorting to move class definition one level up. First I am adding it to the grandparent node but then my reference to class definition node is stale and I cannot use it.

```
var nodeExpression
var nodeMethod
var nodeClassDef
```

When I modify `nodeExpression` a whole new world is generated; how can I quickly get the matching nodes in that new world for `nodeMethod` and `nodeClassDef`?

Comment: @eric-lippert may be you can give some advice on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at creating `SyntaxAnnotation`s on the nodes you want to find after changes.  A convenient way to do this is through the `TrackNodes()` extension method on `SyntaxNode`.

You can provide a list of nodes, and then find them after a re-write using `GetCurrentNodes()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. That was very helpful. As I understood tracking nodes is implemented by anotations.